# How to optimise reading in millions of data | AoC 2023 Day 5 Part 2 | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, memory-management, heap-memory

I need a bit of help with my Part 2 solution for [day 5](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/5#part2). My code below works fine with the sample data provided in the exercise brief, and it returns the correct answer. However, when I replace my input data with the provided [puzzle input data](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/5/input) I keep getting memory issues related errors, or it just takes forever to run and then it eventually flatlines. I'm using Visual Studio Code and node.js, if that helps.

I'd appreciate any help in optimising my code. ChatGPT wasn't that helpful with making the code more efficient. Thanks in advance! :)

```
const fs = require('fs');

function readFile(filePath) {
    try {
      return fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error reading file: ${error.message}`);
    }
}  

// pull in the .txt file input data
let input = readFile('G:/My Drive/Visual Studio Code/Advent of Code/2023/day05.txt').split(/\r?\n/);

function isNumberInRange(number, start, end) {
    return number >= start && number <= (start + end);
}

function mappedNumber(number, start, mapStart) {
    return (number - start) + mapStart;
}

function mapSeeds2Location(seeds, location, mapping) {
    for (const originalSeed of seeds) {
        let seed = originalSeed; // we want to keep the original seed number so the mapSeeds2Location function is able to continue through the other seed numbers
    
        for (let i = 0; i < mapping.length; i++) {    
                  
            for (const map of mapping[i]) {
                var maps = map.split(" ").map(Number);
        
                if(isNumberInRange(seed, maps[1], maps[2])) {                    
                    seed = mappedNumber(seed, maps[1], maps[0]); // replace the original seed number with the next mapped number
                    break; // once we have mapped a number, then move onto the next mapping
                };                
            }
    
            // once we get to the final mapping (humidity-to-location) then push the location value to the array
            if(i == mapping.length - 1) {
               location.push(seed);
            }
        };    
    }
}

const arrays = input.reduce((acc, item) => (item === '' ? acc.push([]) : acc[acc.length - 1].push(item), acc), [[]]);

var [seeds, ...mapping] = arrays; // separate the first array from the rest - this is to separate the list of seeds

seeds = seeds[0].split(" ");
seeds.shift();
seeds = seeds.map(Number);
var location = [];

console.log(seeds);

/* Part One
mapSeeds2Location(seeds, location, mapping)
console.log("part one answer = " + Math.min(...location));*/

// Part Two
for (let x = 0; x < seeds.length; x+=2) {
    for (let y=0; y<seeds[x+1]; y++) {
        // for each seed in the range, find the mapped location number
        mapSeeds2Location([y + seeds[x]], location, mapping)
    }
}

let minLocation = location[0];
for (let i = 1; i < location.length; i++) {
    if (location[i] < minLocation) {
        minLocation = location[i];
    }
}

console.log("part two answer = " + minLocation);

// console.log("part two answer = " + Math.min(...location));
// Apparently Math.min() hinders performance if the array is large, thats why I had commented it out
```

Here is the example input data below. With this example data, the expected answer is **46**.

```
seeds: 79 14 55 13

seed-to-soil map:
50 98 2
52 50 48

soil-to-fertilizer map:
0 15 37
37 52 2
39 0 15

fertilizer-to-water map:
49 53 8
0 11 42
42 0 7
57 7 4

water-to-light map:
88 18 7
18 25 70

light-to-temperature map:
45 77 23
81 45 19
68 64 13

temperature-to-humidity map:
0 69 1
1 0 69

humidity-to-location map:
60 56 37
56 93 4
```

My code works with the example data, but flatlines when I'm given the below data.

```
seeds: 1310704671 312415190 1034820096 106131293 682397438 30365957

seed-to-soil map:
2879792625 0 201678008
2425309256 1035790247 296756276
2722065532 1759457739 157727093

soil-to-fertilizer map:
3279397405 3488165796 12149874
3463813711 3827946213 157129363
877824710 677909236 28172718
2215709448 1746651561 307558709

fertilizer-to-water map:
4253122607 1473424614 41844689
3040447798 2659805568 46237011

water-to-light map:
4066036887 2992193346 95912236
531075515 493316918 162009008
3260565192 854248031 437396028
1341316194 4205924684 89042612

light-to-temperature map:
2756401132 2384899493 13749631
1805522143 3592221700 7705711
4040180922 3043888225 254786374

temperature-to-humidity map:
0 211826810 113744983
1875147430 1816023480 774831860
699941162 0 211826810
443679044 325571793 256262118
3531946076 1280528675 186911617

humidity-to-location map:
1901561222 3703467123 151931974
1317500428 2570191181 151780331
3872524156 3690324750 13142373
2109423630 249685414 30437999
```

Comment: it's a bit hard to help without example input data and expected output data

Comment: Are you about to access the hyperlinks in my main post, @JaromandaX? You snuggled see the example input data and expected outcome there?

Comment: Not sure if there's a need for an aggressive tone.
Anyways, I've added the input data for those who do not have an AoC account.

Comment: what aggression? the second link is pointless